# Why does NSTextField become clickable only after I click on the strings?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextfield

I want to create a `NSTextField` with a clickable link embedded in it. So I wrote the following code in `viewDidLoad:` (the `textField` is connected via `@IBOutlet`):

```
    textField.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    textField.selectable = true

    let templateString = "Please check out "
    let linkString = "the following page"
    let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: templateString + linkString)
    string.beginEditing()
    string.addAttributes([NSLinkAttributeName: appPageURLString, NSFontAttributeName: NSFont.systemFontOfSize(11.0) ], range: NSMakeRange(templateString.characters.count, linkString.characters.count))
    string.endEditing()

    textField.attributedStringValue = string
```

However, the text field doesn't seem to be clickable when I run the app:

[image]

And when I tried selecting the text field, it finally becomes clickable ,with the string moving to the bottom-right slightly and turning thick:

[image]

This is so terrible interface. Why does this happen? And how can I make it clickable at launch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131943/why-do-hyperlinks-sometimes-not-show-in-an-nstextfield-with-an-nsattributedstrin?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Found https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1487/_index.html and translated it to swift:

```
        attString.beginEditing()
        attString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: url.absoluteString, range: range)
        attString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.blueColor(), range: range)
        attString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value:NSNumber(integer: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue) , range: range)
        attString.endEditing()
```

And that shows the underline (and blue font) when displaying the textfield.

The 'url' variable is a NSURL.